# Raspberry Pi 4 keeps crashing, possibly due to Plex or External Harddrive

Tags: raspberrypi, plex

I'm at my wits end and prepared to throw this Raspberry Pi at the wall.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4b, installed the latest Ubuntu, and have no problems. Then I install Plex, sign in, and it starts to read the files on my external hard drive and it crashes. After a hard reboot, it will either crash immediately after loading Ubuntu or wait until I open Firefox and Plex before crashing.

Got no idea what I'm doing wrong, just that I've followed youtube videos, know absolutely nothing about Linux or Ubuntu so I don't poke around or type in codes that aren't on tutorials. Any idea what's causing the issue?

Comment: Please provide OS, product & release details. You mention the latest Ubuntu, but didn't specify if you're asking about Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop? or Ubuntu Server?  What Ubuntu product did you install?  Was it an official Ubuntu tutorial you followed? or provide a link or commands you actually executed on your *unstated* Ubuntu product.

Comment: Crashes can display different symptoms. Edit your question to clearly explain the crash you experience each time. Recall that we are not there; we cannot see it happen.